# How should in right way connecting MongoDB in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello i am new in Nodejs & MongoDb.
I created controllers for API where i want create new items in `MongoDB`, edit, search items.
Now i am connecting to `MongoDB` via `mongoose` in main file `server.js`. 
But i need that i can create, edit in `editor.js`.
I tried to export `mongoose` module, but it was unsuccessfull.
How i can do this in right way?

my structure

[image]

```
`editor.js` file - where i want have access to database
const models = require('./../models');
const client = require('./../../server');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let db;
// const db = client.db('todo');
module.exports = {
    getNewsById: async (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.params);
        // console.log(req);
        res.send({oK: 'ok'});
    },
    createNews: async (req, res) => {
        const newItem = req.body;
        newItem['publishedAt'] = Date.now();
        console.log('HERE', client);
        console.log('HERE2', client.db.collection('test').insertOne({
            item: 'canvas',
            qty: 100,
            tags: ['cotton'],
            size: { h: 28, w: 35.5, uom: 'cm' }
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have created the simple MongoDB, express app using typescript have a look. you will get the idea.
https://github.com/rahulshrm2109/NodeTypescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In editor.js after importing mongoose, you can simply load your model using -

```
const db = require('mongoose');
const testModel = db.model('test');
```

And then you can call your db queries similar to -

```
testModel.insert(...);
testModel.find();
```

Once you have built your model using mongoose, it is available in the application. You just need to get it through mongoose.

If you need more help, you can refer to my sample project at https://github.com/kravigupta/nodejs-express-mongo-auth

Comment: thanks, i forgot import model,
now i use this construction
`       const News = new NewsModel(newItem); News.save((err, doc) => {  if (err) throw err;   res.send(doc) })`
but when i call `find(), insert()` - show me error that this methods is `undefined`

Comment: Can you please update your question with NewsModel definition?

Comment: const NewsModel = db.model('News');

Comment: also i fond new issue
        `NewsModel.create(newItem, (err, doc) =>  res.send(doc));`

Comment: Please update your question or raise another one if it is a separate issue. You don't need to call new on NewsModel. Mongoose does that for you. Once you get it from db.model(), you can use that directly to perform operations.

Answer (score -1):

For every new developer who is learning node.js, the first thing they go with the MongoDB connection with the node.js.

I will suggest you keep the MongoDB connection URL, username and password in a separate file say it db.config.js file and then import that file into you server.js or app.js or main file of your node.js and then connect mongo with the try catch block to handle the error. IF you need to learn in more details then you can refer to this [link](https://codesquery.com/connect-node-js-with-mongodb-using-mongoose/).